# Как подключить fontawesome в gulp?

Tags: gulp, шрифты, fontawesome

Пробую подключить fontawesome в сборщик gulp, но у меня какая-то проблема с подключением шрифтов. Прошу подсказать, где я допускаю ошибку.

Мой gulpfile, сюда я подключил задачу icons по аналогии с fonts, при этом шрифты из библиотеки fontawesome я скопировал в ../src/fonts/*

```
'use strict';

/* параметры для gulp-autoprefixer */
var autoprefixerList = [
    'Chrome >= 45',
    'Firefox ESR',
    'Edge >= 12',
    'Explorer >= 10',
    'iOS >= 9',
    'Safari >= 9',
    'Android >= 4.4',
    'Opera >= 30'
];

/* пути к исходным файлам (src), к готовым файлам (build), а также к тем, за изменениями которых нужно наблюдать (watch) */
var path = {
    build: {
        html: 'assets/build/',
        js: 'assets/build/js/',
        css: 'assets/build/css/',
        img: 'assets/build/img/',
        fonts: 'assets/build/fonts/'
    },
    src: {
        html: 'assets/src/*.html',
        js: 'assets/src/js/main.js',
        style: 'assets/src/style/main.scss',
        img: 'assets/src/img/**/*.*',
        fonts: 'assets/src/fonts/**/*.*'
    },
    watch: {
        html: 'assets/src/**/*.html',
        js: 'assets/src/js/**/*.js',
        css: 'assets/src/style/**/*.scss',
        img: 'assets/src/img/**/*.*',
        fonts: 'assets/srs/fonts/**/*.*'
    },
    clean: './assets/build/*'
};

/* настройки сервера */
var config = {
    server: {
        baseDir: './assets/build'
    },
    notify: false
};

/* подключаем gulp и плагины */
var gulp = require('gulp'),  // подключаем Gulp
    webserver = require('browser-sync'), // сервер для работы и автоматического обновления страниц
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'), // модуль для отслеживания ошибок
    rigger = require('gulp-rigger'), // модуль для импорта содержимого одного файла в другой
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'), // модуль для генерации карты исходных файлов
    sass = require('gulp-sass'), // модуль для компиляции SASS (SCSS) в CSS
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'), // модуль для автоматической установки автопрефиксов
    cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css'), // плагин для минимизации CSS
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'), // модуль для минимизации JavaScript
    cache = require('gulp-cache'), // модуль для кэширования
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'), // плагин для сжатия PNG, JPEG, GIF и SVG изображений
    jpegrecompress = require('imagemin-jpeg-recompress'), // плагин для сжатия jpeg 
    pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'), // плагин для сжатия png
    rimraf = require('gulp-rimraf'), // плагин для удаления файлов и каталогов
    rename = require('gulp-rename');

/* задачи */

// запуск сервера
gulp.task('webserver', function () {
    webserver(config);
});

// сбор html
gulp.task('html:build', function () {
    return gulp.src(path.src.html) // выбор всех html файлов по указанному пути
        .pipe(plumber()) // отслеживание ошибок
        .pipe(rigger()) // импорт вложений
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.html)) // выкладывание готовых файлов
        .pipe(webserver.reload({ stream: true })); // перезагрузка сервера
});


// сбор стилей
gulp.task('css:build', function () {
    return gulp.src(path.src.style) // получим main.scss
        .pipe(plumber()) // для отслеживания ошибок
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) // инициализируем sourcemap
        .pipe(sass()) // scss -> css
        .pipe(autoprefixer({ // добавим префиксы
            browsers: autoprefixerList
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(cleanCSS()) // минимизируем CSS
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./')) // записываем sourcemap
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css)) // выгружаем в build
        .pipe(webserver.reload({ stream: true })); // перезагрузим сервер
});

// сбор js
gulp.task('js:build', function () {
    return gulp.src(path.src.js) // получим файл main.js
        .pipe(plumber()) // для отслеживания ошибок
        .pipe(rigger()) // импортируем все указанные файлы в main.js
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.js))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) //инициализируем sourcemap
        .pipe(uglify()) // минимизируем js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./')) //  записываем sourcemap
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.js)) // положим готовый файл
        .pipe(webserver.reload({ stream: true })); // перезагрузим сервер
});

// перенос шрифтов
gulp.task('fonts:build', function () {
    return gulp.src(path.src.fonts)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.fonts));
});

gulp.task('icons:build', function() {
    return gulp.src(path.src.fonts)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.fonts));
});

// обработка картинок
gulp.task('image:build', function () {
    return gulp.src(path.src.img) // путь с исходниками картинок
        .pipe(cache(imagemin([ // сжатие изображений
            imagemin.gifsicle({ interlaced: true }),
            jpegrecompress({
                progressive: true,
                max: 90,
                min: 80
            }),
            pngquant(),
            imagemin.svgo({ plugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }] })
        ])))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.img)); // выгрузка готовых файлов
});

// удаление каталога build 
gulp.task('clean:build', function () {
    return gulp.src(path.clean, { read: false })
        .pipe(rimraf());
});

// очистка кэша
gulp.task('cache:clear', function () {
    cache.clearAll();
});

// сборка
gulp.task('build',
    gulp.series('clean:build',
        gulp.parallel(
            'html:build',
            'css:build',
            'js:build',
            'fonts:build',
            'icons:build',
            'image:build'
        )
    )
);

// запуск задач при изменении файлов
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(path.watch.html, gulp.series('html:build'));
    gulp.watch(path.watch.css, gulp.series('css:build'));
    gulp.watch(path.watch.js, gulp.series('js:build'));
    gulp.watch(path.watch.img, gulp.series('image:build'));
    gulp.watch(path.watch.fonts, gulp.series('icons:build'));
    gulp.watch(path.watch.fonts, gulp.series('fonts:build'));
});

// задача по умолчанию
gulp.task('default', gulp.series(
    'build',
    gulp.parallel('webserver','watch')      
));
```

Следом я подключил scss файлы fontawesome таким образом:

```
@import "../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss";
@import "../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss";
@import "../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss";
@import "../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss";
@import "../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/v4-shims.scss";
```

Затем я подключаю шрифты через my.scss, таким вот образом:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fa-solid-900';
    src: url('../fonts/fa-solid-900.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

На выходе я получаю подключенные scss файлы, но не подключенные сами шрифты, в консоли браузера обращение к шрифту по неверному адресу (в адресе присутствует "webfonts", этот путь указан в одном из scss файлов, т.е. у меня почему-то не подключается шрифт.

[image: скриншот ошибки в console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых вы совершаете бессмысленные действия в двух местах:

```js
gulp.task('fonts:build', function () {
    return gulp.src(path.src.fonts)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.fonts));
});

gulp.task('icons:build', function() {
    return gulp.src(path.src.fonts)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.fonts));
});

// таск "watch"
gulp.watch(path.watch.fonts, gulp.series('icons:build'));
gulp.watch(path.watch.fonts, gulp.series('fonts:build'));
```

Это банальные дубликаты, удивительно что ваш код вообще работает.

Проблема заключается в том что вы подключаете в "**my.scss**" файлы которые имеют свои объявления `@font-face`. Вот пример из файла "**regular.scss**" который вы подключаете:

```
@import 'variables';

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: $fa-font-display;
  src: url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-regular-400.eot');
  src: url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-regular-400.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-regular-400.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-regular-400.woff') format('woff'),
  url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-regular-400.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-regular-400.svg#fontawesome') format('svg');
}
```

Здесь `#{$fa-font-path}` это и есть папка "**webfonts**" как определено в "**_variables.scss**":

```
// Variables
// --------------------------

$fa-font-path:         "../webfonts" !default;
$fa-font-size-base:    16px !default;
$fa-font-display:      auto !default;
$fa-css-prefix:        fa !default;
$fa-version:           "5.10.1" !default;
$fa-border-color:      #eee !default;
$fa-inverse:           #fff !default;
$fa-li-width:          2em !default;
$fa-fw-width:          (20em / 16);
$fa-primary-opacity:   1 !default;
$fa-secondary-opacity: .4 !default;
```

Вы можете изменить переменную прямо там, но это не рекомендуется, нужно переопределить ее в своем локальном variables файле.

Рекомендую посмотреть как это делают профи:
https://github.com/agragregra/OptimizedHTML-5

Там по ссылке на автора можно найти подробное видео на русском.